# How can i give the dummy Time period in camunda?

Tags: java, camunda

How can i give the dummy time period in Camunda.
For instance, the process is needed to be skip sometimes.

[image: The repeated process image]

but the timer will always be expecting some value or else it will throw an error . So i need a dummy or a standard value which can be used to skip the process.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a value for the timer in the property panel of the modeler.

This will let the timer fire after 10 seconds:

[image: timer modeler]